# How to specify a "standard", not CR, servo

Tags: servo

What do you name a servo that rotates to a specific angle and stops there, to differentiate it from a continuous rotation servo, a linear servo, or any of the other varieties?

I've seen them specified as "positional rotation" servos, but this doesn't seem to be an industry standard. Is there an accepted term to explicitly specify the most common kind of servo, that rotates to a specified position and stops there?

Comment: The really key question is if you are talking about a typical inexpensive PWM-signalled *hobby* servo (or a more robust workalike) or if you are talking about a more traditional/robust/powerful industrial type of servo, which is a very different sort of thing.  If you are trying to specify a hobby-type servo for industrial use, that may be the source of your problem - they do sort of exist for people who want to try to extend a hobby-type approach, but tend to be limited.

Comment: A continuous rotation 'servo' is a hobby servo that has been modified (feedback pot disconnected from the output shaft) to make it **not** a servo.

Comment: I'm looking for an adjective. You can say the noun "servo" and everyone knows that's short for servomotor. You can google "CR Servo" or "Linear Servo" and those will bring back search results of specific motors. What adjective do you stick on the front of "servo" to specify the common variety of servomotor, that seeks a fixed angle?

Answer (score 3):

Servo is servo. Anything with negative feedback is servo. What you are talking about is a servo feature, position control. There are many more.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your are trying to describe a *servo-driven rotary actuator*.

You might find some useful pointers on Wikipedia's [Rotary Actuator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_actuator#Servomotors) page.